# Add cadvisior to istio service mesh (kubernetes) to collect metrics with prometheus in pods

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, istio, cadvisor, servicemesh

I just recently started to understand the istio service mesh and I need help
I deployed an bookinfo example from the istio service mesh documentation.
Here are the applied manifests:

- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.20/samples/bookinfo/platform/kube/bookinfo.yaml
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.20/samples/bookinfo/networking/bookinfo-gateway.yaml
- https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/release-1.20/samples/addons
  Where and what should I add in these manifests and which manifest should I use so that I can collect metrics using cadvisor from bookinfo microservices?

I tried to solve this by using these manifestos along with the above manifestos:
https://github.com/antonputra/tutorials/tree/main/lessons/135/monitoring
but as expected, nothing came of it

I've read the documentation of cadvisor and prometheus, but so far I can't write my yaml so that everything works, because I'm still new to this